# passing javascript value into html link

Tags: javascript, variables, text

I assume this is just a beginners issue, I would like to add the value of my variable urlvar1 into a link.
However it looks like this is not working.

```
document.write('<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID="'+urlvar1+'" title="project" frameborder="no" border="0">Your browser does not seem to handle frames properly, but you can go directly to the survey <a href="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID="'+urlvar1+' ">here</a>')
```

Comment: please post more code!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra double-quote `"` in each `href` attribute.

It currently reads like:

```
href="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID="string"
```

where it should read like:

```
href="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID=string"
```

See below for the working string:

```
document.write('<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID='+urlvar1+'" title="project" frameborder="no" border="0">Your browser does not seem to handle frames properly, but you can go directly to the survey <a href="http://www.xxx.xx?ATID='+urlvar1+'">here</a>')
```